# Weird window size bug with Geary

Tags: desktop, pantheon-mail

When I opened up Geary today, the window spans wider than the screen and is super narrow. I can't resize the window or maximize, I can only close it.[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try to upgrade your distro. You can check for updates in the AppStore or just type :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If it doesn't work reinstall geary.

Comment: I may have to just reinstall. I have no idea how/why that happened. Weird.
Thanks for the response!